# laravel complex query building with join and groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I am new to laravel and have the following query in core PHP that needs to be laravel query.

```
$query="select distinct(c.c_id), 1 'companyToken',c.companyname,u.email,creation_date,CONCAT(eu.firstname,' ',eu.lastname) 'Name' , group_concat(pk.package_name) 'Package Name/Service' ,  c.notes 'Notes' , c.demo_status 'Demo Status'  from ee_company c
                 left join et_company_payment_methods cpm on cpm.c_id=c.c_id
                 left join et_packages pk on cpm.package_id = pk.id
                 inner join (SELECT *
                 FROM `ee_users`
                 WHERE c_id IS NOT NULL
                 GROUP BY c_id) u on u.c_id=c.c_id
                 left join ee_users eu on eu.id=c.referred_by_user_id
                group by c.c_id";
```

i am just getting started with laravel so finding it difficult to convert such a complex query.

the existing system works fine with this query.

i tried building it with laravel.

```
$company = DB::table('ee_company')
            ->leftJoin('et_company_payment_methods', 'ee_company.c_id' , '=', 'et_company_payment_methods.c_id')
            ->leftJoin('et_packages', 'et_packages.id', '=', 'et_company_payment_methods.package_id')
            ->join('ee_users',function($join){
                                  $join->on('ee_company.c_id', '=', 'ee_users.c_id')
                                     ->whereNotNull('ee_users.c_id')
                                     ->groupBy('ee_users.c_id');
                })
            ->leftJoin('ee_users', 'ee_users.id', '=', 'ee_company.referred_by_user_id')
            ->groupBy('ee_company.c_id');
```

it gives me following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::groupBy()
```

Comment: If you don't wish to convert it to Laravel's Eloquent syntax you could simply use `DB::raw(...)`. Not an actual answer, I know, it's just worth mentioning.

Comment: Laravel's fluent query builder is an awesome tool if you ask me. I suggest you learn how to convert this query to the fluent syntax step by step which will be a good exercise in learning the tool in general.

Comment: SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: It would have been more clear if you mentioned the tables, columns you have, and required output; Here is the link for documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries where you can learn.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have added the code that i tried and also the error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$company = DB::table('ee_company')
        ->leftJoin('et_company_payment_methods', 'ee_company.c_id' , '=', 'et_company_payment_methods.c_id')
        ->leftJoin('et_packages', 'et_packages.id', '=','et_company_payment_methods.package_id')
->join(DB::raw('SELECT *
             FROM `ee_users`
             WHERE c_id IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY c_id'),function($join){
                              $join->on('u.c_id', '=', 'c.c_id');
            })
->leftJoin('ee_users', 'ee_users.id', '=', 'ee_company.referred_by_user_id')
->groupBy('ee_company.c_id');
```